# How to serve a new ssl cert

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

here is what i did so far:

1. Requested my Certificate Authority to provide a CERT for connecting Jenkins (running on https://) to nexus CLM (running on https://).
2. Provided them with CN ( i used hostname, as CN )

They gave me :

Reference number: 
Authorization code:

Using these, i created:

1. el-ci-clm.der
2. nexus-clm-priv.key
3. nexus-clm.csr

i actually used the private key and csr to get the .der file

First you create a private key with the command:
openssl genrsa -out -priv.key 2048

Then create a csr with the private key with the command:
openssl req -new -sha256 -key -priv.key -out .csr

As instructed in the link provided above the Common Name must be the reference number

Now:

what do i do next, as i have 2 things to accomplish ( i think ) 
1. Have to create a bundle with company.crt, commonpolicy.crt and third.crt
2. create a java keystore and add all these certs in the right order to the key store
once i have the .jks file, i can use that in the reverse proxy 
and
on the jenkins side add the same keystore to the jvm

once i have the .jks file, i can use that in the reverse proxy 
and
on the jenkins side add the same keystore to the jvm

am i missing something?

```
$ openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in el-ci-clm1.der  -out nexus-clm-public.cer

unable to load PKCS7 object
140735252787280:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1199:
140735252787280:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_D2I_EX_PRIMITIVE:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:767:
140735252787280:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_TEMPLATE_NOEXP_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:699:Field=type, Type=PKCS7
140735252787280:error:0906700D:PEM routines:PEM_ASN1_read_bio:ASN1 lib:pem_oth.c:83:
```

so do i need to make a pkcs7 file from a der ?

Comment: DER and PEM define only the 'outer' encoding of a file, not the contents. You can have PKCS7 data in PEM format or in DER format. You can have a single (X.509) cert in PEM or DER, and in neither case is a cert the same as a PKCS7. If the file named `.der` was named by someone competent it _should_ be DER. **_If_ it is PKCS7 DER transmitting certs**, a format often described as 'p7b', which you haven't provided any evidence for or against, **add `-inform der`** to your `openssl pkcs7` command line.

Comment: openssl pkcs7 -inform der -print_certs -in el-ci-clm1.der  -out el-ci-clm1.cer
unable to load PKCS7 object
140735100084304:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1199:
140735100084304:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:374:Type=PKCS7
what am i missing

Comment: Maybe your file isn't a PKCS7 at all, or maybe it's messed up somehow. If in normal text tools like `more vi notepad` it begins with or contains a line of the form `-----BEGIN something-----` followed by several lines of all or nearly all letters and digits and a similar `-----END` line, post what `something` is. If it's mostly gibberish with a few words here and there, `openssl asn1parse -inform der <el-ci-clm1.der` and post that (or if too long the first screenful).